# Trouble scraping the names from a certain website

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I've come across such a webpage which seems to me a bit misleading
to scrape. When I go the address "https://jobboerse2.arbeitsagentur.de/jobsuche/?s=1" it takes me to a page with "suchen" option. After clicking "suchen" it opens a new layout within this tab and takes me to a page with lots of names. So, the site address is same again "https://jobboerse2.arbeitsagentur.de/jobsuche/?s=1".
I would like to scrape the names of that page, as in "Mitarbeiter für die Leerguttrennung (m/w)". Any help would be highly appreciated.
What I wrote so far:

```
Sub WebData()
    Dim http As New MSXML2.xmlhttp60
    Dim html As New htmldocument, source As Object, item As Object

    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://jobboerse2.arbeitsagentur.de/jobsuche/?s=1", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    Set source = html.getElementsByClassName("ng-binding ng-scope")
    For Each item In source
        x = x + 1
        Cells(x, 1) = item.innerText
    Next item
    Set html = Nothing: Set source = Nothing
End Sub
```

The links are incremented like these as per xhr in developer tool but can't figure out what is the number of the last link.

"https://jobboerse2.arbeitsagentur.de/jobsuche/pc/v1/jobs"
"https://jobboerse2.arbeitsagentur.d...00&FCT.ANGEBOTSART=ARBEIT&FCT.BEHINDERUNG=AUS"
"https://jobboerse2.arbeitsagentur.d...EBOTSART=ARBEIT&FCT.BEHINDERUNG=AUS&offset=12"
"https://jobboerse2.arbeitsagentur.d...EBOTSART=ARBEIT&FCT.BEHINDERUNG=AUS&offset=24"
"https://jobboerse2.arbeitsagentur.d...EBOTSART=ARBEIT&FCT.BEHINDERUNG=AUS&offset=36"

Comment: When you press the `search` button, then a request goes to the server and data are returned as `json`. This data are then displayed in the grid. Sou what you could try is to press the `search` button programmatically first, wait until the data will be displayed in the grid and then filter the elements by class name.

Comment: Right you are sir dee. I also noticed it in the first place but can't go further as i can't think of clicking that button using xmlhttp request method. Thanks.

Comment: Yes but you can try to use IE object. Then it is possible to click. Or you can just call `https://jobboerse2.arbeitsagentur.de/jobsuche/pc/v1/jobs?FCT.AKTUALITAET=100&FCT.ANGEBOTSART=ARBEIT&FCT.BEHINDERUNG=AUS` and [parse](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) the returned `json` in VBA yourself.

Comment: Thanks sir dee for your response. You are very close to what i'm looking for. I also found one "https://jobboerse2.arbeitsagentur.de/jobsuche/pc/v1/jobs". However, is there any way to get all the links, as in your one and my one so that i can finally make use of those links using json or jscript cause you know the page holds lazy loading method?

Comment: Oh yes you are right,the page doesn't display all the results at once, because there could be potentially to many items. Instead the result is load by parts. When you watch the url you see there is query string parameter like this `&offset=12`. This parameter has values from 12, 24, 36, 48, 50 etc. So in 12-record steps. So you'll have to have a loop and will send your requests changing this parameter `offset` for each call. When the result is empty (or perhaps an error occurs???) then you reached the end of the data and you know there are no other data on the server.